# printing a string with additional characters

Tags: assembly, nasm

The following code prints more characters than indicated in string. I'm using NASM

```
section .text

global main

main:
    mov ah,0x09
    mov dx, varr
    int 0x21 ; print string in dx

    mov ah, 0x4c
    mov al, 0x00
    int 0x21 ; exit program code 0

section .data
    varr db "asd",'$'
```

And prints random chars followed of the *asd* string as

```
'♦V☺'♦'♦☺☺☺ ☻               8♣µ Æ♣¶ ↑ Æ♣        ♣               ═! asd
```

[image]

why is this? what I'm failing. I disassembled it with x-rays and looks correct, the address of the *varr* (0x10) corresponds to the start of the string.

Comment: Put this in your .data section: `varrLength equ  $-varr`

Comment: .com file? `org 100h`.  .exe file? `mov ax, data`/`mov ds, ax`.

Comment: What if you do `mov ax,seg varr` / `mov ds,ax` at the beginning of the program?

Comment: Thanks Frank Kotler. Worked with org 0x100.